# Loa: using deep space gates

Tags: sword-of-the-stars-2

Consider the following picture:

[image: space highway]

We have two distant systems, Marshak and Regis, connected by a highway of gates. Just off the highway, there are a bunch of planets - Azar, Crysta, Lambda. Obviously, the fastest way to reach one of those unconnected planets is to fly to the closest gate and bounce off of it. However, attempting to route a fleet to one of the unconnected planets has the ships automatically using STL, completely ignoring the gates.

I also attempted to send a fleet from Marshak to Regis, then when it was close to Crysta, changed the mission to survey Crysta. The result: the fleet attempted to return all the way to Marshak and STL to Crysta, instead of just...flying for one turn to the planet it was already almost on top of!

Is there a way to route ships to use the faster approach, namely flying partway through the highway and leaving it when close to the target?